# Object debugger and 502 error

Tags: facebook, debugging, sharing

I was wondering why I can't share my website page on facebook. When I mean "can't" I should say "can't like every one else".
When I share something on FB, I always have this ugly link, no image, no description are extracted from my website. 
I tried to find answers, but I didn't find any thing that works. So I used the Object debugger, to see what's going on...

here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpierre-nizet.fr%2Fblog

This debugger tells me that there is a 502 error... Ho wait... this website really exists and is fully fonctionnal (if you don't believe me : http://pierre-nizet.fr/blog). So my questions are : WTF? What's going on? I would like to understand what's wrong and fix this...

Could you please help me ?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: The debug tool shows that your page is tryin to redirect to `http://www.redirection.tld/`, which does not make any sense at all. That the redirect/502 error does not occur when accessing the site using a browser, points to something being misconfigured at your server’s side. Some “bot blocking” tool/script maybe, that does not let Facebook’s scraper access your page. Talk to your server admin – let him have a look into the server logfiles, etc.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I will contact him...